# Instrument in java level using byte-buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have a code for Thread Pool example as follows

```
public class RunThreads{
static final int MAX_TASK = 3;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Runnable r1 = new Task("task 1");
    Runnable r2 = new Task("task 2");
    Runnable r3 = new Task("task 3");
    Runnable r4 = new Task("task 4");
    Runnable r5 = new Task("task 5");

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_TASK);

    pool.execute(r1);
    pool.execute(r2);
    pool.execute(r3);
    pool.execute(r4);
    pool.execute(r5);
    pool.shutdown();
}}
```

and

```
class Task implements Runnable{
private String name;

public Task(String s)
{
    name = s;
}
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=5; i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
            {
                Date d = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                System.out.println("Initialization Time for"
                        + " task name - "+ name +" = " +ft.format(d));
                //prints the initialization time for every task
            }
            else
            {
                Date d = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                System.out.println("Executing Time for task name - "+
                        name +" = " +ft.format(d));
                // prints the execution time for every task
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println(name+" complete");
    }

    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

The i create a small agent for instrument java `ThreadPoolExecutor` as follows

```
public class Agent {

public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
            .type((ElementMatchers.nameContains("ThreadPoolExecutor")))
            .transform(
                    new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                            .include(MonitorInterceptor.class.getClassLoader())
                            .advice(ElementMatchers.any(), MonitorInterceptor.class.getName())
            ).installOn(instrumentation);
}}
```

Can we Instrument java class like ThreadPoolExecutor using Byte Buddy. When i debug ThreadPoolExecutor class working.But when i try this using  agent ThreadPoolExecutor class never works.

Edit 
This is my MonitorInterceptor

```
public class MonitorInterceptor {


@Advice.OnMethodEnter
static void enter(@Advice.Origin String method) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(method);

}
```

Edit

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
            .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
            .ignore(none())
            .type((ElementMatchers.nameContains("ThreadPoolExecutor")))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
                    .constructor(ElementMatchers.any())
                    .intercept(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class))
                    .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                    .intercept(Advice.to(MonitorInterceptor.class))
            ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you configure it explicitly, Byte Buddy does not instrument core Java classes. You can change that by explicitly setting an ignore matcher that does not exclude such classes.

In this context, it should not be necessary to configure an initialization strategy when using Advice.

You might also want to limit the scope of your advice, right now you intercept any method or constructor.

For finding out what is wrong, you can also define an AgentBuilder.Listener to be notified of errors.

Comment: I added a Listener as follows `.with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())` and i get this `[Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker [null, null, loaded=false]
[Byte Buddy] IGNORE java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker [null, null, loaded=false]
[Byte Buddy] COMPLETE java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker [null, null, loaded=false] ` . Is it okay . So i think its ignoring the java class

Comment: Did you try ignore(none()) in the builder?

Comment: ` .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())` I  used this and i hope my problem is now fixed.

Comment: I got another problem , in this its not showing constructor of `ThreadPoolExecutor`  do i need to add `.constructor(ElementMatchers.any())` for this ?

Comment: Depends on how your i strumentation looks like now

Comment: I am still using above agent and i added my MonitorInterceptor

Comment: This constructor problem occurs only when try to instrument `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I try this for normal class and its perfectly working for constructor and methods.

Comment: No error messages and when i add `.constructor(ElementMatchers.any())`  the method part also not working

Comment: i added my modified agent if i change `ThreadPoolExecutor` for normal class its works correctly.

Comment: You probably want to enhance a class by `.visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(any())`.

Comment: I also need to instrument java.lang.Thread class but its not showing either listener also . but when debugging its occurs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167228/discussion-between-shehan-aklanka-perera-and-rafael-winterhalter).

Answer (score 1):

Using Rafael Winterhalter answer i get solved this problem. I create an agent as follows ,

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
                .type(ElementMatchers.nameContains("ThreadPoolExecutor"))
                .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder
                        .visit(Advice.to(ThreadPoolExecutorAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.any()))
                ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

Using this we can instrument Java class.Form this constructor giving like this

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor,java.lang.Runnable)
```

But in code constructor not like that, its is

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                              int maximumPoolSize,
                              long keepAliveTime,
                              TimeUnit unit,
                              BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
             Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
    }
```

So I expect something like

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)
```

I used javassist to get constructor and get its as what byte-buddy gives. So using `.ignore(ElementMatchers.none())` and `visit(Advice.to(ThreadPoolExecutorAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.any()))`we can get all constructors and methods in Java level class