# fails to instrument threadPoolExecutor by bytebuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I encounter the same problem with this post.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321938/instrument-in-java-level-using-byte-buddy/55032131#55032131
```

when I use the code instrument threadpoolexecutor,

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
            .type(ElementMatchers.nameContains("ThreadPoolExecutor"))
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder
                    .visit(Advice.to(ThreadPoolExecutorAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.any()))
            ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

I got this error, How to solve it?

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot represent public org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler) as given method constant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to get a `Method` instance injected while you are instrumenting a `Constructor`. Switch the parameter type and it should work out.